# Create many-to-many relationship between two entities via multiple columns

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, fluent

I have the following four tables:

**Customer**

```
Id
FirstName
...
```

**ConsumptionPoint**

```
Id
Address
...
```

**Invoice**

```
Id
InvoiceNumber
CustomerId
ConsumptionPointId
...
```

**ContractAccount**

```
Id
ContractAccountNumber
CustomerId
ConsumptionPointId
IsCurrentDelivery
...
```

I want to get the ContractAccountNumber for an Invoice.

Is it possible to create some kind of a relation between these both to access the ContractAccount(s) of an Invoice directly?

Currently I'm doing something like:

```
invoice.Customer.ContractAccounts
    .Where(ca => ca.ConsumptionPoint == invoice.ConsumptionPoint &&
    ca.IsCurrentDelivery == true).FirstOrDefault();
```

**update** in SQL I would simply do a join with multiple conditions:

```
SELECT i.Id AS InvoiceId, ca.Id AS ContractAccountId, 
ca.ContractAccountNumber
FROM Invoices i
LEFT JOIN ContractAccounts ca
ON i.ConsumptionPointId = ca.ConsumptionPointId
AND i.CustomerId = ca.CustomerId
WHERE ca.IsCurrentDelivery = 1
```

**update 2:**

Basically I just want to get rid of the `ca.ConsumptionPoint == invoice.ConsumptionPoint` in the Where-Clause and want to define this inside the relation.

Actually this is a many-to-many relationship: one Invoice can link to many ContractAccounts (via different Customer/ConsumptionPoint combinations) and one ContractAccount can link to many Invoices. Is there no way to tell .net to build a many-to-many relationship, based on the combination of two custom columns?

Comment: You could create a VIEW in the database to expose only the data with the desired conditions and create a 1-1 relationship between your actual entity and your VIEW

Comment: @Cleptus the idea with a VIEW sounds interesting. I think this should work. I will try this. And yes, it should be `ca.IsCurrentDelivery` thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deeper investigation I have found a solution.

Basically it's just a many-to-many relationship. So we can add the appropriate properties to Invoice and ContractAccount Model:

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public ConsumptionPoint ConsumptionPoint { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ContractAccount> ContractAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class ContractAccount
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public ConsumptionPoint ConsumptionPoint { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we just have to configure the relationship manually:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
        .HasMany(i => i.ContractAccounts)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(ca => new { ca.CustomerId, ca.ConsumptionPointId })
        .HasPrincipalKey(i => new { i.CustomerId, i.ConsumptionPointId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<ContractAccount>()
        .HasMany(ca => ca.Invoices)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(i => new { i.CustomerId, i.ConsumptionPointId })
        .HasPrincipalKey(ca => new { ca.CustomerId, ca.ConsumptionPointId });
}
```

And that's it. Now I can do something like:

```
invoice.ContractAccounts
    .Where(ca => ca.IsCurrentDelivery == true).FirstOrDefault();
```

which is way better than before.

Thanks for your comments, which pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need two keys for that. Using EF core you can create a relationship like that:

Invoice:

```
public class Invoice
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int InvoiceNumber {get; set;}
  public int CustomerId {get; set;}
  public Customer Customer {get; set;}
  public int ConsumptionPointId {get; set;}

  public int ContractAccountId {get; set;}
  public ContractAccount ContractAccount {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class ContractAccount
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int ContractAccountNumber {get; set;}
  public bool IsCurrentDelivery {get; set;}
}
```

Then configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
  .HasOne(b => b.ContractAccount)
  .WithOne()
  .HasForeignKey<Invoice>(b => b.ContractAccountId);

//probably already exists in your code
modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
  .HasOne(b => b.Customer )
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey(b => b.CustomerId);
```

And then you can access it directly from invoice: `invoice.ContractAccount`

Comment: I believe you may have skipped that the relation is not `1-1` per-se but `1-1(filtered data)`. Being the relevant part in the question "_the combination CustomerId/ConsumptionPointId (with IsCurrentDelivery==true) is unique_"

Comment: Might be, description is written in a great amount of complexity. Also I guess there is a problem with that unique index - it limits two records per CustomerId/ConsumptionPointId, one with IsCurrentDelivery = true and other = false

Comment: This solution would result in a `ContractAccountId` foreign key in `Invoice` entity. But this is not wanted. One ContractAccount can be set to `IsCurrentDelivery=false` and another ContractAccount could be created for the same Customer/ConsumptionPoint combination. In such situation, the Invoice should not be updated manually by changing the foreign key. It should be updated "on-the-fly" (by requesting the ContractAccount with current delivery for the Customer/ConsumptionPoint equivalent).
See my updated solution in plain SQL in question.